# Re-order variables without re-reading full data set

Tags: sas

I know that variables can be re-ordered in a data set using, for example, the RETAIN statement. Say data set D1 has variables v3, v2 and v1 (and in that order), and I want them to appear in the data set as v1, v2 and v3 (viewing from left to right), I can do the following:

```
data D1;
  retain v1 v2 v3;
  set D1;
run;
```

Can this be done without reading the entire data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't actually change the order of the variables without reading the entire dataset (as this changes how they are stored physically).  Depending on the reason *why* you want to reorder them, you may be able to reorder them as part of the process for which you use them by creating a view:

```
data d1v/view=d1v;
retain v1 v2 v3;
set d1;
run;
```

Then you could use `d1v` as you would have used `d1` in most (but not all) cases.